# DRF UserProfile object is not iterable

Tags: django, django-rest-framework

Реализовал функционал, что бы по эндпоинту можно было создавать юзера и его профайл одновременно.

файл models.py

```
class UserProfile(models.Model):
    user = models.OneToOneField(User, related_name='user_profiler' ,on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    mid_name = models.CharField(max_length=200, blank=True, null=True, default=None)
    phone_number = models.BigIntegerField(blank=True, null=True, default=None)
    age = models.IntegerField(blank=True, null=True)
    birthday = models.DateField(blank=True, null=True)
    positin = models.CharField(max_length=255, blank=True, null=True)
    vip_status = models.BooleanField(default=False)
```

файл serializers.py

```
class CreateUserProfileSerializer(serializers.ModelSerializer):
    class Meta:
        model = UserProfile
        fields = [
            'mid_name',
            'phone_number',
            'age',
            'birthday',
            'positin',
            'vip_status',
        ]
        read_only_fields = ['user', 'created_by', 'updated_by', 'update_by_id', 'created_by_id']

class CreateUserSerializer(serializers.ModelSerializer):
    user_profiler = CreateUserProfileSerializer(many=True)
    password = serializers.CharField(write_only=True)

    class Meta:
        model = UserModel
        fields = ["id", "first_name", "last_name", "username", "password", "email", 'user_profiler']

    def create(self, validated_data):
        user_profiler_data = validated_data.pop('user_profiler')
        user = UserModel.objects.create_user(**validated_data)
        for userprofile in user_profiler_data:
            UserProfile.objects.create(user=user, **userprofile)
        return user
```

файл views.py

```
class CreateFullUserView(generics.ListCreateAPIView):
    authentication_classes = [SessionAuthentication]
    permission_classes = [permissions.AllowAny]
    serializer_class = CreateUserSerializer


    def get_queryset(self):
        user = self.request.user
        queryset = User.objects.filter(id=user.id).prefetch_related(Prefetch('user_profiler', UserProfile.objects.filter(user=user)))

        return queryset
```

Отправляю по эндпоинту следующий json

```
{
    "first_name": "mytestuser",
    "last_name": "Test",
    "username": "User",
    "password": "Yewfsa_12412wqr",
    "email": "dasdas@maicl.com",
    "user_profiler": [
        {
            "mid_name": "pupkun",
            "phone_number": 380957777777,
            "age": 42,
            "birthday": "1912-12-12",
            "positin": "This is user user"
        }
    ]
}
```

Юзер и юзерпрофайл создаётся, однако я получаю ошибку. Когда просто открываю урлу, то всё работает.

```
'UserProfile' object is not iterable
```

Подскажите, в чём может быть проблема ?

Answer (score 0):

```
    user_profiler = CreateUserProfileSerializer(many=True)
```

Замените `True` на `False` и будьте счастливы.

У вас же связь 1 к 1

Comment: Ошибка пропала. Но теперь я получил другую ошибку и пользователь с профайлом не создался.
Ошибка : AttributeError: 'list' object has no attribute 'items'

Comment: Смотрите, где использовать словарь. В вашем вопросе нет этого участка кода